# Product's custom options are not appearing

Tags: product, custom, magmi

IF I'm adding a product manually in Magento, it's custom options are appearing on Product page.

If I'm importing products using Magmi, custom options are appearing in Magento admin and has options is set to 1 on product's view.phtml but custom options are not appearing.

```
if ($this->hasOptions()) {
echo 'inside loop';
echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true);
}
```

I'm not getting any html content from `echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true);` for products which is imported through magmi.

I see in **catalog_product_entity_varchar** table with records with value **container2** for products which are created using Admin panel but this value is **container1** if they are imported using Magmi. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I'd to update the csv column **options_container** with value **container2**.

Answer (score 1):

I also run into this issue when I was creating simple product with custom option using Magmi.

You can use **Default Values setter v0.0.5** in Magmi. you can set default value for **options_container** with **container1** or **container2** then options will use this default value otherwise Magmi will use **NULL** or **container2** as default.

[image]

I hope this will help to others too!